# Socket exception while Load testing

Tags: weblogic, jmeter, socketexception, f5

While load testing with JMeter we are receiving `Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException` for all the requests once peak load is reached.

Here is the server config:

```
JMeter -> F5 (load balancer) -> 2 legs of Weblogic servers.
```

What could be the reason of getting socketexception?
Any help in this regard is highly appreciated!

Comment: ANy news on that ? was my answer helpful ?

Answer (score 0):

This is your server starting to reject connections or timeouts on client side.

This means your server cannot handle the load correctly.